Sound volume issue - can't control PCM
I have an Asus UX490UA laptop and have been using Ubuntu for the past few years and my technical skills are limited, but I love using Linux after a lifetime of Windows.
My volume has always had an issue where I couldn't control the PCM volume, when the Master changed. I fixed it using the following helpful article -
Adjust PCM volume?
After some updates to my system, I would have to repeat the fix, probably four times a year on average.
Recently, after updating to 24.04, I can't get the volume to behave. I'm guessing this is due to Pulseaudio being superseded by Pipewire.
My sound card is an 'HDA Intel PCH'.
So I wondered if anyone had some tips for me please of how to get the PCM volume of my system to change or merge with the Master volume?
Best regards and thank you for your time
